# What did Harry Potter do, between the murder of his parents and getting dropped of at the Dursleys?

Tags: harry-potter

As far as I remember, Harry's parents were killed at night, then Hagrid picked him up from the rubble (before the Muggles got there), and sometime after that he met Sirius who gave Hagrid his bike, and after that, Hagrid brought Harry to the Dursleys (with Dumbledore and McGonagall being also there). The Dursley timeline was similar - at night, the Potters were murdered, people were happy and partying all day in the streets, owl everywhere, and Harry was left at the front door the next night.

So basically, ~24 hours have passed between the murders (and being picked up by Hagrid) and being left at the Dursleys doorstep.

Is there any canon explanation of where Harry was at this time, and what he was doing (well.. technically, what others were doing with/to him, since he was a baby)?

Comment: The answer to your specific question is "sleeping, pooping, eating and crying" since that's basically what babies do.